# Unable to render simple graph in d3.js by reading data from MySQL using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I'm trying to plot a simple line graph with a value **'IV'** on the y-axis and **'Time'** on the x-axis. I read these values from my MySQL database. Here is the PHP code that I am using:

```
<?php
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "root";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="db";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "SELECT  data.IV, data.Time FROM  data";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $myquery ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

Here is the resulting JSON:

```
[{"IV":"230.8","Time":"15:01:17+22\r"},{"IV":"233.7","Time":"15:06:57+22\r"},{"IV":"230.8","Time":"15:36:25+22\r"},{"IV":"234.5","Time":"15:40:38+22\r"},{"IV":"238.7","Time":"15:41:39+22\r"},{"IV":"238.7","Time":"15:41:50+22\r"},{"IV":"238.7","Time":"15:43:05+22\r"},{"IV":"230.8","Time":"15:01:17+22"},{"IV":"223.8","Time":"15:52:17+22"}]
```

So I've modified the examples I found online to try and render the data. However all I get is a blank page. Here's my code could someone please tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong? I've been stuck at this for days.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.IV); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Time); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("gj.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.IV = +d.IV;
                d.Time = +d.Time;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.IV; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Time; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I can see:
[image]

I suspect the problem is with the presence of +(digits)\r at the end of Time. However I need to work with data in this format.

Comment: can u provide link to the online tutorial that your followed?

Comment: I think you're right about the time formatting. You can normalize the formatting inside the javascript / D3 portion by including a small forEach loop similar to advice here (http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/getting-data.html) and making sure you have the time formatting correct per here (http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/formatting-date-time-on-d3js-graph.html). Conversely, you could do it in the php after you've selected the data from the database. Either way there may be a little string formatting required,

Comment: @iBlue I used the tutorial here: https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-using-php-to-extract-json-from-mysql (Using PHP to extract json from MySQL)

Comment: @d3noob Thank you! I will have a look. I am inserting the data into MySQL by reading from a serial port using a Python script, which is possibly the origin of the carriage return character. So I will modify my back end to remove the '\r' character and then use the string formatting in the links you posted.

Comment: Excellent! That's a good option.

Comment: @d3noob, if you could have a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374839/plot-points-on-a-graph-with-multiple-axes-in-d3-js) it would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a console.log on your data array after trying to coerce the time into a number, you'll see that the Time attribute on each object is NaN, which is preventing it from rendering. Look into d3's time formatting function to parse your number strings into actual javascript date objects before converting to numbers.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: Thank you @ne8il, i shall try implementing that. What do you mean by NaN format though?

Comment: NaN stands for Not a Number. So it doesn't recognize the variables value correctly (as a unit of time), which is what has been surmised in the comments above.